# First floor vs ground floor, usage origin

Tags: word-usage

Ground floor – First floor:

> - In British English, the floor of a building which is level with the ground is called the ground floor. The floor above it is called the first floor, the floor above that is the second floor, and so on.
> - In American English, the floor which is level with the ground is called the first floor, the floor above it is the second floor, and so on.

(Collins COBUILD English Usage)

Though there are exceptions to the above-mentioned usage,( and exceptions are not the issue here)   in public buildings in the U.S., for instance,  it’s also possible to call the street-level floor the ground floor, like in Britain, *but  how come that in the UK and Europe  the ground level floor  and the first floor are  respectively  referred to as the first floor and  the second floor in the U.S.  (and so on for higher floors)*. Was it a custom imported into the U.S. from a different culture?

Related:["Ground floor" vs. "first floor"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/ground-floor-vs-first-floor).

Comment: Related: [How are basement levels in shopping malls designated?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197498/how-are-basement-levels-in-shopping-malls-designated) and very *loosely*  [How to refer to an apartment on a specific floor?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103454/how-to-refer-to-an-apartment-on-a-specific-floor)

Comment: The answer is simple, a number system that skips zero, like -2, -1, 1, 2 is common to primitive cultures, where more civilized cultures have invented the zero, and would count -2, 1, 0, 1. It just means the US and Sweden are more primitive than old Europe.

Comment: I live in the United States, and I see "G, 2, 3, ..." in elevators quite often.

Answer (score 5):

You can read this article and make your own assumption about why Americans use such a system:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey#Numbering

In my opinion, when you use the word "floor", you should start from 1 (on the ground). Because you have a floor (surface) there, don't you? This is logical.

Comment: So your answer is that it is because Americans just  adopted a more logical numbering system compared to the rest of the world?

Comment: I like the wiki link. It's interesting.

Comment: My answer is that European system is just a historical legacy. Although as a  programmer I can understand counting floors starting with 0.

Comment: Actually if you want to be logical, ground should be zero, because then the levels below ground (basement and beyond) start from -1. Every floor's number tells you how many stories you are away from ground level, and in what direction, which is mathematically consistent.

Comment: @JBentley if you live on floor on ground. If inside house- 1st floor. You go out of house- 0. Basment just basement or call -1 if need number for just one basement.

Comment: @Kangarooo Apologies, but I do not understand your comment

Comment: @JBentley That really depends on what your numbers represent.  If they are based on distance between the ground and the literal floor of the floor, then yes, zero makes reasonable sense for the ground floor; however, if they are based on how many floors you actually possess on either side of the ground, then floor zero is pure fancy.  In that latter case, it would be the imaginary floor in the infinitely small point between the ground floor and the basement.  In both cases, the ground itself is the zero point, and what matters is what you are measuring. You can't possess a zero'th dollar, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The American convention is that the floor ***inside*** a building which is on the ground, is called the *first floor* and the floor above that is called the *second floor* and so forth.

**Why the difference?**

This is my theory:
The term *ground* doesn't need to be qualified, there is no such thing as a ‘second ground’ whereas any building can have one or more floors or storeys.  Neverless in many hotels, the first floor is often referred to as a *lobby*

> **[First Floor/ Ground Floor](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/firstfloor.html)**
>   In the US, the first floor of a building is also the ground floor, but
>   in Europe the first floor is the floor above the ground floor, and the
>   second floor is the one above that. This is important information for
>   novice American travelers trying to find their hotel rooms.
>    <sub>Paul Brians’ *Common Errors in English Usage*</sub>

[image: enter image description]![image]

<sub>Images from [English Club.com](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/floors-building.htm)</sub>

An American native speaker on Word Reference writes

> [We use "ground floor" and "first floor" interchangeably.](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=513000&p=2906324#post2906324) If you walk
>   up a flight of stairs, you reach the second floor, whether you call
>   the floor you started on the ground floor or the first.

Similarly on a different English language forum, a native speaker confirms

> In the US, [“ground floor” and “first floor” mean the same thing and
>   are used interchangeably](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/47491-How-to-use-quot-Ground-Floor-quot-and-quot-First-Floor-quot-and-what-s-the-difference?p=204187&viewfull=1#post204187). Usually elevator buttons marked ‘B1’, ‘B2’
>   etc. do indeed refer to “basement”. Sometimes they will say ‘LL1’,
>   ‘LL2’, which stands for “lower level” (but still means “basement”.)

Comment: Yes, but from a more basic perspective, what we in Europe call ground floor, basically the floor at ground/street level, is what Americans would naturally call  *first floor*. There are many exceptions and complications with big buildings but still the distintcion remains, and it is something typical of the U.S.

Comment: @Josh61 yes, but Americans have a knack for simplifying things, and there will always be exceptions, especially where language is concerned. But as for "why", the ground is the ground, you can't go up a ground, but you can go up a level/floor/storey.

Comment: So the answer is: Americans' knack for simplifying things? (I am seriuos). To me it sounds illogical...however simpler it may look.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, I offered a plausible explanation, but I am neither an architect nor an American. Finding the origin for this convention will prove to be very difficult. Don't forget that Americans also use the term *storey*, and *elevator* whereas BrEng will use *floor* and *lift*. Putting a date on these historical differences is, I think, impossible.

Comment: Sorry, probably I am not clear enough, the quesion is not about the use of floor vs storey etc. but on the number assigned to them. EU *ground floor*  is US *first floor*, EU *first floor*  is US *second floor* and so on...language misunderstanding on this issue are not rare I guess. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: I was just giving examples, your question is almost like asking "Why don't Americans say *lift* instead of *elevators*? Why do Americans say "first floor" instead of "ground floor"? They just do, and as you correctly pointed out in your post, the boundary line is fuzzy. But generally speaking there is *also* this difference between the US and the rest of Europe. What system do they use in Australia or in India? Probably the BrEng one :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA India and most of Asia (perhaps not China and Japan) use the European system, as do most former British administered countries such as those who drive on the left. Australia has tried to be clever and abandoned the word *floor*. They talk about Level 1 (ground), Level 2 (First floor) etc. All this is fine until you go to the massive new Norfolk and Norwich University Hospital, which is built on two levels. What is the Ground on one side is the first on the other. And their numbering system's a nightmare!

Comment: Once buildings are going down as well as up, I'd say that zero for ground-level is the most logical.  I've worked in buildings where the buttons in the lifts/elevators are numbered 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2.  What could be neater?

Comment: @DavidGarner Yes, I've heard of *ground* being compared to **zero** level. It makes sense, then the floor above should be the first (as you listed) and never second. So I'm guessing you must British! But I am not passing any judgement, I'm not saying one system is better than another.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, yes, I'm a Brit, who'll admit that where there's a Brit/Us divide, it's more often the US word that's most logical [sidewalk and thumbtack say what they mean, unlike pavement and drawing-pin], but the mathematician in me likes ground-level = zero.

Comment: @DavidGarner oh, but I like the term *pavement*, and it makes perfect sense to me, a pavement is a type of floor, (in Italian it's *pavimento*) and the Ancient Romans *paved* the roads.

Comment: ... but it says nothing about its *function* -  *walking* down the *side* of the street!

Comment: The term *floor* (i.e. pavement), doesn't need *any* additional explanation unlike "walk" which is too general.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught (Anglo New Zealander with 20 years in Europe) that

a) a building has a floor on the ground, the ground floor

b) an additional floor is added and it's the first [extra] floor. BTW this will have to have a proper structure rather than beaten earth which many ground floors used to be when animals lived on the ground floor and the people lived above. So "first" would also refer to the first separate structure of a floor.

Just as logical as any other numbering system.