# Is it common for native English speakers to confuse "18th century" with "the 1800s"?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english, catachresis

As a non-native English speaker, I've only ever referred to "1700-talet", meaning "the 1700s" or "the 18th century".

In English, it's by far most common to say "18th century" to refer to the years "1700-1799". My brain, even to this day, keeps thinking of the "1800s" when somebody says "the 18th century". I have to actively make an effort to force-retrain my brain each and every time.

I extremely rarely hear anyone say "the 1700s" in English.

I understand that the first century was years 0-99, so that's why the "100s" are the "2nd century". But still. This way of referring to centuries just doesn't exist in my language, or, if it does, I've literally *never* heard or read it. I'm unsure how common it is outside English in general.

You can imagine how confused I used to be as a child seeing "20th Century Fox" at the end of *The Simpsons* in the 1990s: "Huh? Is this show from the future?!" And then they changed it to the "21st Century Fox" after year 2000, so the confusion continued...

Comment: Centuries go from '01-'00, not '00-'99, since there was no Year 0. The 21st century/next millennium started in 2001, not 2000, despite what New Year's Eve 1999 revelers might have had you believe.

Comment: Well I confess, I am a native speaker and find I always translate in my head, “20th century” to “the 19-hundreds” before processing further. I even mentally do the equivalent for “21st century” ! I don’t often have to translate back again as I am rarely speaking or writing about past centuries .

Comment: What is "talet"?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh "-talet" is the Swedish suffix equivalent to the plural s at the end of "the 1800s" or "the 50s".

Comment: It's interesting to note that "Xth century" is the most common way to refer to centuries, but nobody says "9th decade" or "199th" decade about the 1980s.

Comment: @jkej In fields like medicine and ageing/developmental research, it isn't uncommon to refer to, say, "the 9th decade", meaning when people are aged in their 80s, as the first decade covers ages 0 through 9, and so on. For me at least, it still always requires a bit of mental arithmetic to understand what is meant.

Comment: @jkej we do talk at least about the first or the second decade of the century.

Comment: @Džuris I haven't heard that very often, and I can imagine it's mostly because "the 00s" and "the 10s" are awkward to say. My main point was that there's a very clear dominance of "the Xs" when talking about decades.

Comment: Old memorial inscriptions also sometimes say that the person died, for example 'in their fortieth year', i.e. they were 39. Incidentally, my father, born 1907, used to refer to that decade as 'the 1900s'. When, more recently, I began to hear people referring to 'the 1800s', it only gradually dawned on me that they meant the 19th century and not 1800-1809!

Comment: This sort of confusion (and yes, I think many native English speakers find it confusing, especially for centuries other than the 20th/21st) is exactly why I think **people should use the ‘XX00s’ form more often**: a term like ‘1700s’ is concise, clear, unambiguous*, and easy for everyone to understand. I don't know why it's not more popular! (* Of course, there is an ambiguity as to whether it refers to a whole century, or to the first decade within that century. But in my experience that's usually clear from the context.)

Comment: Apropos of confusion, I remember being baffled as a child that a TV show about the 1900s was title [_The Twentieth Century_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twentieth_Century). Then, in 1967, as if to intentionally compound the confusion, the network changed the name of the show to _The 21st Century_ while retaining the same host/narrator (Walter Cronkite) and format.

Comment: I don't see what's confusing. 18th century ends in 1800, that's easy enough

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238495/first-floor-vs-ground-floor-usage-origin

Comment: All programmers who use C  type languages (where the array index starts at 0 and not 1) make the same mistake in the code. It is called the [1-off bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).  This is why languages which start indexing at 1 are better as it has less of these bugs and are less confusing (even though math people like to start the index at zero). The same issue happens with  century numbering :). Nothing to do with English speaking or not.

Comment: @Nasser Indexing from one doesn't improve this specific confusion. Our years are 1-indexed, and yet here we are.

Comment: It's not common, but I have seen native speakers confuse the n-00s with the n-th century.

Comment: I can't see how anyone can collect factual data to answer your question. Yes, people do sometimes make this mistake. But how often? I don't know, and I don't think anyone else does either. My guess is that someone who is speaking or writing usually gets it right but that people who are listening or reading might misunderstand them - you don't actually say which you are asking about.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Most people think the 21st century started on 1 Jan 2000. I consider the first century to have been 99 years long because of the lack of a year zero. It's important to remember that the West didn't have zero as a number until the early 13th century (thanks to Leonardo Bonacci, aka Fibonacci). The concept of having a name / symbol for nothing was perceived as contradictory because now nothing was something. An early name for zero was cipher precisely because the concept was so puzzling.

Answer (score 47):

As a first-language English speaker, my experience is that I have come to automatically associate the specific terms "20th century" and "21st century" with the 19--s and 20--s respectively, whereas I do find myself doing a mental adjustment of the form "subtract and convert to the (n-1)00s" for other cases of "n-th century". The established terminology is a bit annoying, but not something that I would expect to cause actual confusion as long as I have any time at all to think about it.

Comment: As an aside, I sympathize with the difficulties ESL speakers face here as I'm always tripped up in French by the fact that not only do French writers use the same "nth century" convention as in English, but it seems usual to write the ordinal number as a Latin numeral, so I encounter stuff like "XVIIe siècle" where I need to convert XVII to 17, then subtract one from 17 to get the sense of "the 16--s".

Comment: In French academic literature, *s.v* is also common...

Comment: I *always* have a mental hiatus when translating between year numbers and century numbers. It may be because I'm a programmer. The same happens to me with misbegotten programming languages that use 1-based arrays rather than 0-based arrays. (There should be a year zero CE, and the first century ought to be century zero. Or that's what my brain tries to insist! )

Comment: @nigel222 Good to hear that I'm not the only one.

Comment: @nigel222: Hmm how come? "The 20th element is Array[19]": no mental hiatus?

Comment: @nigel222: There **is** a [year zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero) according to astronomers, and also according to ISO 8601.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica No. In everyday usage, do you enter a house on its first floor? (Perhaps in some countries, you do).

Comment: @nigel222 in the US you most definitely do, and the entire concept of "zero floor" or anything like it is very foreign to most Americans

Comment: @Esther: I've seen buildings where rooms in the basement are numbered "0xx", as if it were a "0th floor".

Comment: @Esther most people are not Americans, though

Comment: @njzk2 Most English speakers (as a first language) probably are.

Comment: @TechInquisitor except for all the Brits and Aussies and Canadians in the crowd. And those who live in British territories, etc. We Americans do tend to be _very_ America-centric.

Comment: @FreeMan That does not contradict Tech Inquisitor's point. The number of people in the US that speak English as their first language currently hovers around 240 million, while the number of people worldwide that speak English as their first language is estimated to be 400 million. A reasonable conclusion is that the majority of *native* speakers of English speak American English.

Comment: I used to make a distinction between _the 19th century_ (1800-1900) and _the 1800s (1800-1810) until I discovered that other people don't, and when they said _the 1800s_ they often meant the whole century. (And if anybody starts quibbling about the way I've expressed the limits of the ranges, **I don't care**. You can go and play your infantile superiority games with somebody else.)

Comment: @ColinFine: Ah, that's interesting. This interpretation is new to me, but it does make a kind of sense! I think we can say, "the 2000s", to mean 2000-2009? But that may not hold a century from now...

Comment: @FreeMan: Despite not being American, Canadians do agree with then that the ground floor is the 1st floor, so that's another ~26 million native English speakers used to that convention (and quite a few fluent speakers who grew up Francophone or other, although Europe has a lot of people fluent in English used to the other convention if we broaden to include fluency).  That's a separate thing from what you were objecting to, I realize, but njuffa's numbers show a small majority for that.

Comment: Wait before you hear about French *rez-de-chaussée* and *rez-de-jardin* - yes , we have TWO ground floors, which are one above the other (and then there is floor 1). The idea is that on one side of the building you can enter "from the street" (*chaussée*), and on the other side where the ground is higher (1 floor higher), you enter "from the garden" (*jardin*).

Answer (score 24):

Yes, I have seen and heard many native speakers of English make the same mistake. And it works exactly the same way in Dutch: you say *de 18e eeuw* when you mean 1700–1799. And Dutchmen frequently make the same mistake, especially those with less education in history. It is only natural.

P.S. Things like "the late second century B. C." can also be confusing...

Comment: Yes, it's extremely common. Even after 80 years with English, I have to stop and think pretty often about that one. It's a typical fencepost error. For a while I used Italian _Quattrocento_ et al, which is convenient, but you can't use Italian everywhere.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Now I've always found the Italian confusing, for why do they leave out the thousand? And I don't even know how they would say the fifth century.

Comment: Same reason Spanish calls 1900 _Noveciento_. The _mil_ is simply assumed.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yeah but it's confusing, because how do they say the 10th century?

Comment: Who needs to talk about the 10th century?

Comment: @JohnLawler: This sounds like a rhetorical question, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica *il novecento* is the century, while 900 is the year, which is still pronounced *novecento*, but we don't add the article. For the 10th century, we just say *decimo secolo* which is the literal translation of *10th century*.

Comment: (I won't introduce *il secolo decimo-nono* for *the 19th century*.)

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Done it several times (including on schoolwork). One of the most infuriating things about the English language and history. For reference, I’m a native English speaker.

Comment: The reason why we have an error in our century numeric system is because the romans didn't have 0 i ii iii iv v vi... So they jumped straight to 1st century AD in all the european history books until the 12th - 13th century.

Comment: It is not an 'error'. The first year of a person's life is the year ending with their first birthday. The first century AD was the years before 100 AD.

Comment: @KateBunting when did the convention of numbering years in terms of AD start?  It certainly wasn't year 0, and maybe not until well after 100.

Comment: @MarkRansom - According to Wikipedia _This dating system was devised in 525 by Dionysius Exiguus of Scythia Minor, but was not widely used until the 9th century_. However, I wasn't suggesting that people at that time thought of themselves as living in the first century, just explaining how the system works.

Comment: Almost. The first century was the first 100 years, up to *and including* 100 AD (aka 100 CE).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a common mistake. The confusion arises from the fact that there are two common conventions for grouping consecutive years into centuries, and that the boundaries of the resulting centuries are not aligned.

"The 1800s" refers to the 100 years numbered 18xx, i.e. 1800..1899.

"The 18th century" refers to the 18th group of 100 years since the start of the common era. The Gregorian calendar doesn't have a year 0 (the year before 1 CE was 1 BCE) so the first century was the years 1..100, the second century was the years 101..200 and so on. The 18th century, following this pattern, was the years 1701..1800.

Note that the year 1800 was the *first* year of the 1800s, but the *last* year of the 18th century. Similarly, the year 2000 was the last year of both the 20th century and the second millennium.

If there *was* a year 0 in the Gregorian calendar then the two conventions *would* align their centuries on the same boundaries, but if we then wanted to justify calling the 1800s the 18th century we'd also need to refer to years 0..99 as "the zeroth century" which feels kind of weird.

Dates and times are a hot mess and the bane of computer programmers everywhere.

Comment: And there's the problem that "the 1800s" might be used to mean 1800--1809.

Comment: Pick one revision and stop rolling it back.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to check how common the use of numbering historical periods by centuries.  Put into a translation programme the English *'18th century'* and translate it into as many languages as you like.  You will find that all the European romance languages, as well as the germanic languages and Greek, and you will find that they all use 'century'.  In romance languages:  *dixhuitiême siècle* (French); *diciottesimo secolo* (Italian); *achtzehntes Jarhundert* ....  I cannot speak for other language families outside Europe, but Google gives for Hindi *athaarahaveen* (=18th) *sadee* (=century).  Ukrainian also uses this system of historical counting.

It is true that patterns of historical events do not always (or even usually) fit neatly into hundred year chunks.

It is true that many people find it easy to slip up over which ordinally counted century is which cardinally counted 'hundreds', especially, I would argue, with the centuries before the Common Era.

That said, there is nothing wrong with calling the 21st century the 20 hundreds, except that to me, at least, it sounds a bit odd.

Comment: It is perhaps not so strange that if you enter the English phrase "18th century", you get a similar phrase back for most languages. If you instead enter "the 1700s" you get a different answer for most languages. None of that tells you which of them is the preferred term in those languages. For Swedish, Danish and Finish, however, you get something starting with "1700" regardless, because there are no idiomatic equivalents to "18th century" in those languages.

Comment: Also, "the 2000s" probably sounds better if you read it as "the two thousands" instead of as "the twenty hundreds".

Comment: Sure, but *the 2000s* and *the two thousands* refer to 2001-3000, don't they ;)

Comment: @PhilSweet There's certainly a logic to what you're saying, but language is not always that logical. So far "the two thousands" are mostly used to refer to the period from 2000 until now (and maybe the nearest foreseeable future). We might have to wait a couple of hundred years to see how the usage develops.

Comment: @jkej: For Danish (and, I think, Swedish and Norwegian), we most assuredly have idiomatic equivalents of "18th century" (18. århundrede in Danish), and this is the same as the 1700s (1700-tallet).

Comment: @jkej I think you would need to look below the raw statistics at who is making which vocabulary choice.  My raw guess is that you would find that academics, particularly historians, and readers / former students of these tend to use the ordinal option.  Either way the choice should not be a basis for 'date snobbery', like 'scon' versus 'scone' or sugar before/after milk.

Comment: @HeartWare That would not be idiomatic in Swedish. Sure, people might understand what you mean, party due to familiarity with the English expression, but it would strike me as odd. I assumed it was the same for Danish since Google translated "18th century" to "1700-tallet".

Comment: For the next 78 years or so, we can talk about the "two thousands".  What happens after that is probably beyond the control of anyone reading this.  Those who are alive then will likely refer to the 21st century as the "too naughties" or something ridiculous like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not only English speakers, but the other language speakers are in the same boat. While talking about centuries, just add one to the first two digits of the year.

Comment: It's probably from latin. French, italian, Spanish, books all use the same technical enumeration... It's wrong and it's a misnomer. For buldings they say rez de chaussée and ground floor for the 0 value. It's kindof amazing that they never thought of the number zero until indian ten base system. So essentially the origin is due to the latin i ii iii counting system.

Comment: It's not wrong or a misnomer, it's just a natural consequence of the common way people count things. If you hold up a bunch of bananas and ask children to count them, they're going to count starting from one, not zero.  If you tried to teach them to start from zero, you're going to confuse the kids and annoy their parents. That's why it's not wrong.